# Qt My Program quits after using printdialog

Tags: qt, pointers, qt5

After I use my QPrintDialog my complete running program quits and not just the QPrintDialog. I can't explain why.
Here is the source code:

In this snippet I initialisize my PrintDialog function.

```html
void VerteilerData::on_pushButton_calc_clicked()
{
    emit (on_pushButton_Load_clicked());
    //Beim Initialisieren von Printing druck eine 0 übergeben um in Printing vert.getdata zu skippen
    QString QHelp="0";
    Printing druck(this,QHelp);
    druck.print_calculation(vert_anz,pro_idthis);
}
```

Here is the Code where I start my QPrintDialog;
If you need some details, just ask i will add the information

```html
.
.
.
.(Some SQL Queries for the information i need)

{
printAuss(angebot);
}


//Here Starts the Dialog

void Printing::printAuss(const QStringList &entries)
{


    QPrintDialog printDialog(&printer);
       if (printDialog.exec())
     {
         QPainter painter (&printer);
         QList<QStringList> pages;

         paginate(&painter,&pages,entries);
         printPages(&painter, pages);
         painter.end();
         return;
     }
}

void Printing::paginate (QPainter *painter, QList<QStringList> *pages, const QStringList &entries)
{


    QStringList currentPage;
    QImage test(":/pics/BriefbogenGroß.jpg");
    qDebug()<<"Höhe_neu"<<test.height();
    painter->setWindow(test.rect());
    int pageHeight = painter->window().height() -1 * TopGap -1 * BottomGap;
    int y=0;
    foreach (QString entry, entries)
    {    qDebug()<<entries.size();
        int height;
        height= entryHeight(painter, entry);

        if (y+height > pageHeight && !currentPage.empty())
        {

            pages->append(currentPage);
            currentPage.clear();
            y = 0;
        }
        currentPage.append(entry);
        y+= height+ MediumGap;
    }
    if(!currentPage.empty())
        pages->append(currentPage);
 }

int Printing::entryHeight(QPainter *painter, const QString &entry)
{


    QStringList fields = entry.split(" § ");
    QString title = fields[0];
    QString body =fields[1];
    QString price =fields[2];

    QImage test(":/pics/BriefbogenGroß.jpg");
    painter->setWindow(test.rect());
    int textWidth = painter->window().width() - 50* SmallGap;  //Breite
    int maxHeight = painter->window().height();
    qDebug()<<"höhe "<<maxHeight;
    painter->setFont(titleFont);
    QRect titleRect = painter->boundingRect(0,0, textWidth,maxHeight,
                                            Qt::TextWordWrap, title);
    painter->setFont(bodyFont);
    QRect bodyRect = painter->boundingRect(0,0, textWidth, maxHeight,
                                            Qt::TextWordWrap, body);
    painter->setFont(titleFont);
    QRect priceRect = painter->boundingRect(0,0,textWidth,maxHeight,
                                            Qt::TextWordWrap, price);

    return titleRect.height() + bodyRect.height() + priceRect.height() + 4 * SmallGap;
}

void Printing::printPages(QPainter *painter, const QList<QStringList> &pages)
{
    int firstPage = printer.fromPage() -1;
    if(firstPage >=pages.size())
        return;
    if(firstPage== -1)
        firstPage=0;
    int lastPage = printer.toPage() -1;
    if(lastPage == -1 || lastPage>= pages.size())
        lastPage = pages.size() -1;
    int numPages = lastPage - firstPage +1;
    for(int i = 0;i<printer.numCopies();++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<numPages;++j)
        {
            if (i !=0 || j!=0)
                printer.newPage();

            int index;
            if(printer.pageOrder() == QPrinter::FirstPageFirst)
            {
                index = firstPage + j;
            }
            else
            {
                index =lastPage - j;
            }
            printPage(painter,pages[index],index + 1,numPages );
        }
    }

}

void Printing::printPage(QPainter *painter, const QStringList &entries, int pageNumber,int maxPages)
{
    QString Seitenzahl;
    Seitenzahl=QString::number(pageNumber);
    Seitenzahl.append(" / ");
    Seitenzahl.append(QString::number(maxPages));
    painter->save();
    QImage test(":/pics/BriefbogenGroß.jpg");
    painter->setWindow(test.rect());
    qDebug()<<"Image Höchte: "<<test.height();
    painter->drawImage(0,0,test);
    painter->translate(0, TopGap);
    foreach (QString entry, entries) {
        QStringList fields = entry.split(" § ");
        QString title = fields[0];
        QString body = fields[1];
        QString price = fields[2];
        printBox(painter,title,titleFont,Qt::lightGray,false);
        printBox(painter,body,bodyFont, Qt::white,false);
        printBox(painter,price,titleFont,Qt::white,true);
        painter->translate(0,MediumGap);
    }
    //Was Ans ende des Dokumentes schreiben
    if(pageNumber==maxPages)
    {
        painter->translate(0,30);
        QString help;
        help.append("Gesamtnettopreis.....: ");
        help.append(QString::number(gesamtpreis));
        help.append(" €");
        painter->setFont(titleFont);

        int boxWidth = painter->window().width();

        int textWidth = boxWidth -50 * SmallGap; // 2
        int maxHeight = painter->window().height();
        QRect textRect = painter->boundingRect(SmallGap,SmallGap,textWidth,maxHeight,Qt::TextWordWrap | Qt::AlignRight,help);
        painter->drawText(textRect,Qt::TextWordWrap,help);

    }
    painter->restore();
    painter->setFont(bodyFont);
    painter->drawText(painter->window(),
                      Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt:: AlignBottom,
                      Seitenzahl);


}
void Printing::printBox(QPainter *painter, const QString &str, const QFont &font, const QBrush &brush,bool price)
{
    painter->setFont(font);

    int boxWidth = painter->window().width()-50*SmallGap; // -- 45 SmallGap

    // Text Breite
    int textWidth = boxWidth -2 * SmallGap;  // 2
    int maxHeight = painter->window().height();
     QRect textRect;
    if(price==true)
    {
             textRect = painter->boundingRect(SmallGap*23.5,SmallGap,textWidth,maxHeight,Qt::TextWordWrap | Qt::AlignRight,str); //
    }
    else
    {
             textRect = painter->boundingRect(SmallGap*23.5,SmallGap,textWidth,maxHeight,Qt::TextWordWrap | Qt::AlignLeft,str); //
    }

    int boxHeight = textRect.height() + 2*SmallGap;
    painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black,2.0,Qt::SolidLine));
    painter->setBrush(brush);
    painter->drawRect(22.5*SmallGap,0,boxWidth,boxHeight);
    painter->drawText(textRect,Qt::TextWordWrap ,str);
    painter->translate(0,boxHeight);
}
```

Comment: Normal exit or crash?

Comment: normal exit in buy debug console is the following text: C:\Users\user6\Desktop\Coden\build-BachelorUbbenV0-1-Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit2-Debug\debug\BachelorUbbenV0-1.exe exited with code 0    so its exited with code 0

Comment: Your best bet is to use a breakpoint before the location it crashes at. Just giving us code won't help.

Comment: well it doenst crash its exiting

Comment: Its exiting the whole program after finishing the print job or canceling the printdialog window. but it should just exit the printdialog window and not the whole program

Comment: As Poriferous said, add a breakpoint in the function and go step by step, you should see exactly where it exits. You are also not showing us all the function calls that happen in the method so who knows what happens inside.

Comment: if printDialog.exec(); then the print window opens. and even if i dont run my source code, so if i hit the "cancel" button in the QPrintdialog my whole program exits instead of just that window. i am not sure if u rly need breakpoints there. Because u can say its after exec the printDialog and then no matter which Signal happens